# Calculating sum of any two numbers but sum of 999 and 1 in C

Tags: c, debugging

C is not friendly to me. I am writing a programme to calculate the sum of the two numbers. As the input numbers were very large so I tried to use a char array to calculate. I am wondering what might goes wrong because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

My code like this:

```
if (len[0]>=len[1]){...}
else{
    for (int i=0 ;i<len[1];i++){
      if (i <=len[0]){
      temp[i] = (digits[0][i] + digits[1][i] + carry) % 10;
      carry = (digits[0][i] + digits[1][i] + carry) / 10;
    }else{
      temp[i] = (digits[1][i]  + carry) % 10;
      carry = (digits[1][i]  + carry) / 10;
    }}
    if (carry==1){
      temp[len[1]++]=1;

  }
  for (int i=0,j=len[1]-1; i <len[1];i++,j--){
      sum[j]=temp[i]+'0';

  }
```

It works for almost every case until I input 1 and 999
it gives 220 instead of 1000.

I am not sure why the programme doesn't work in this case only.

Comment: You need to post the calling code that shows "i input 1 and 999" and how that fills up `len[]`.  An [mcve]

Comment: You most certainly have [undefined behavior](http://wiki.c2.com/?UndefinedBehavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all you should work on you **indentation** and code in brackets. 
  It helps you and us reading your code. In the code provided the indentation is not clear nor correct and could be the first issue if the code provided is this one.
- Use [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). Here 'j' could be less than 0.
- Call `printf("%d\n", sum[j]);` in the for loop.

```
    for(int i=0,j=len[1]-1; i <len[1];i++,j--)
    {
        sum[j]=temp[i]+'0';
        printf("%d\n",sum[j]);
    }
```

- If you want to print the sum you shall do

```
    for(int i=0,j=len[1]-1; i <len[1];i++,j--)
    {
        sum[j]=temp[i]+'0';
    }
    int mySum = 0;
    for(int index=0; index <sizeof(sum);index++)
    {
       mySum += sum[j];
    }
    printf("%d\n", mySum );
```

- if you want a working code, rework all of your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const char * number1_c = "1111";
const char * number2_c = "123";

int number1,number2;

int main()
{
   number1 = atoi(number1_c);
   printf("Sum of x = %d\n",  number1);
   number2 = atoi(number2_c);
   printf("Sum of y = %d\n",  number2);
   printf("Sum of x+y = %d\n",  number1+number2);
   return 0;
}
```

(if you want to learn how to convert an char* into an int, [google it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-your-own-atoi/)!)

Comment: why downvoting? this IS an answer.

Comment: No it is not an answer it is an advice on how to better identify the error and thus should be a comment.

Comment: the first problem does come from indentation. I mean, at least in the code sample provided. The second problem comes from the call %s instead of %d

Comment: I see but you need to edit your answer since it is not obvious what you are trying to say. Also it is not really possible to tell which type each array stores as of the provided code. The line `sum[j]=temp[i]+'0';` implies that `sum` is of type `char *` or `char[]` where `%s` whould be the correct placeholder.

Comment: answer edited in a clearer way. Concerning `%s` , if  `int` then `%d` , else if `char *` the `+` operator shall not be used. Furthermore, `sum[j]`  cannot be called outside the for-loop, instead of `sum`

Comment: it gives 48
48
48
49
1000

Comment: if i use printf("%c\n",sum[j]); it gives 
0
0
0
1

Comment: so did I answered your question? you can upvote it and choose it :)

Comment: I am afraid not. as long as I prinf, everything looks fine during the process. But if I simply prinf sum, it gives the wrong ans. But still thanks for your kindness.

Comment: do you want a working code or learn from your mistakes? anyway the working code is added in the answer. Enjoy!

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, i do want to learn from my mistakes and improve my code. Your suggestions are helpful

Comment: glad i helped you! you can also can upvote my answer by pressing the upper arrow :)